# Recorrer un arreglo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

no soy muy conocedor en este tema de javascript pero tengo el siguiente problema y es que quiero mostrar el valor de "value" en un alert pero no doy con la sintaxis correcta para lograrlo este sería el array:

```
{
  "id": "5O190127TN364715T",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b",
      "payments": {
        "authorizations": [
          {
            "id": "0AW2184448108334S",
            "status": "CREATED",
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100.00" // Este es el valor que quiero mostrar...
            },
            "expiration_time": "2018-05-01T21:20:49Z",
            "create_time": "2018-04-01T21:20:49Z",
            "update_time": "2018-04-01T21:20:49Z",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: eso es un array o un json?

Comment: Disculpa, tienes razón es un json me equivoqué en el contexto pero el propósito es el mismo, quiero mostrar el valor de "value" en un alert

Comment: Entonces la pregunta seria, como obtener el valor de un campo dentro de un json.... y ya esta contestada, varias veces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let j = {
  "id": "5O190127TN364715T",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b",
      "payments": {
        "authorizations": [
          {
            "id": "0AW2184448108334S",
            "status": "CREATED",
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100.00" // Este es el valor que quiero mostrar...
            },
            "expiration_time": "2018-05-01T21:20:49Z",
            "create_time": "2018-04-01T21:20:49Z",
            "update_time": "2018-04-01T21:20:49Z",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
}
console.log(j.purchase_units[0].payments.authorizations[0].amount.value)
```